# Linking after using f2c

Tags: c, linker, fortran

I used f2c to translate a huge Fortran subroutine into C. The header says the following:

```
/* fourier.f -- translated by f2c (version 20090411).
   You must link the resulting object file with libf2c:
    on Microsoft Windows system, link with libf2c.lib;
    on Linux or Unix systems, link with .../path/to/libf2c.a -lm
    or, if you install libf2c.a in a standard place, with -lf2c -lm
    -- in that order, at the end of the command line, as in
        cc *.o -lf2c -lm
    Source for libf2c is in /netlib/f2c/libf2c.zip, e.g.,

        http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf2c.zip
*/
```

I am using ubuntu 10.04. How can I link the object file with libf2c?

Comment: Meta-Question:

It seems like you're trying to get access to a FFT-function written in Fortran from Java.. Why not take the short-path, ignore the old Fortran stuff and link you Java-code against the FFTW library. It is most likely more performant than the Fortran code anyways..

Comment: Can you help me with this? I just learned Fortran and know very little about it. I have a program written in Java that needs to get the coefficients of a fourier sine sum of squares series. My professor wrote a Fortran program that does that such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to install the `libf2c2-dev` package -- but as the `f2c` package already depends on it, all you may need is to add `-lf2c` to your Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling the resulting C file with gcc?   Then add "-lf2c -lm" to the gcc compile command.

Why not compile with a Fortran compiler, such as gfortran?  It's easily available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

By passing `-lf2c -lm` to the line which will create the executable from the objects. Which compiler are you using on Ubuntu? GCC?

```
gcc -c fourier.c -lf2c -lm
```

Could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Well - no direct answer to your linking problems, but:

Since you're working with Linux: Why don't you compile you fortran code as is and link it directly with the C-code? GCC can do that. Converting the code is of course doable but it is by no way required.

Nils

Comment: Because I need to use the resulting C code in a Java library. :P

Comment: With the ISO_C_Binding, you can declare Fortran subroutines to use the C calling convention, so that they are directly callable just as if they were C.

Comment: @Earl Bellinger - Oh.. I see. Java, C, JNI-Stuff.. (I currently work in that field as well). I know of no direct way to do this. It could be doable with GCC, but I haven't ever tried it. 

Would be a great blogpost if you get it working.. Otherwise: Just write a wrapper in C :-)